Cannot unsave questions
I have been unable to unsave questions (by clicking the bookmark icon between the downvote button and the timeline icon) for three days. All other UI widgets are working properly. I use Safari browser on a Mac to browse this site. Is this a problem on my end or on MSE?

There were these two recent post on [meta.se]:
Cannot remove a post from saves from the Q&A page and
Unable to unsave posts when showing them again, or even just after being refreshed, using the left side icon.

@MartinSleziak Thanks. Glad to know the real cause of the issue.
